# Covariance Matrix Eigenvalue Distribution Relation to Size

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues, wishart-distribution

I'm trying to run PCA on sample covariance matrices of various sizes (ranging between 20 x 20 to 4000 x 4000). Assume the data follows a joint multivariate normal distribution.

While derivations are great, I'm asking from an applied perspective. Bonus points for easy-to-understand papers and packages in R that help with the following:

1. Is there a way to test the statistical significance of the eigenvalues? Or assign a probability of a given eigenvalue occurring?
2. How does the relative magnitude of the eigenvalues change as we scale up the size of the covariance matrix? E.g. Let's say the first 3 principal components explain ~80% of the variance for a 20x20 matrix (not sure if this is true in practice). If we were to scale this up to a 4000x4000 matrix, would we still expect to see ~80% of the variance explained by the first 3 PCs?

Assume the population covariance matrix is **not diagonal** and is of full rank. Thanks!

Comment: For "statistical significance of eigenvalues" to have any meaning, you need to specify a null hypothesis.  What do you have in mind for that, especially in light of your desire to assume a non-diagonal covariance matrix?  Is your question (2) about *data* or about the *model*?

Comment: So how familiar are you with results in http://statweb.stanford.edu/~imj/WEBLIST/2001/LargestEigPcaAnnStat01.pdf ?

Comment: @StasK I glanced through the paper but the results in the paper all assume the identity as the data covariance matrix .... please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @whuber I'm working with time series data so I'd use a long-term covariance matrix as my null and a short-term as my test. Regarding (2) -- I'm not sure but please take this as an example: If we take the eigenvalues of an n x n correlation matrix C, the R-squared of PC1 is given by Eig_1/trace(C) = Eig_1/n. Does R-squared of PC1 tend to 0 as the matrix grows? Or does Eig_1 grow with n?

Comment: Trying to clarify the same two questions asked by @whuber: (1) So you have a particular fixed population cov matrix C that you are willing to assume for your null? (2) This is not clear until you specify how your C is supposed to change "as the matrix grows".

Comment: @amoeba (1) That is correct. (2) I want to understand whether it's possible to make general statements about the R-squared of the PCs associated with the largest eigenvalues for all correlation matrices as you increase the size. For example, if you had a 10 x 10 correlation matrix of uncorrelated data N(0,1) data and you took the R-squared of PC1, you'd get Eig_max/n.. If you let n increase for a diagonal matrix, would the R-squared of PC1 tend to 0%? Secondly, if you had data with significant common structure (e.g. financial data), how stable would the R-squared be?

Comment: (1) Okay, this is clear now. (2) If all data are uncorrelated and N(0,1) then the population covariance matrix is equal to identity and the first PC explains 1/n of total variance. Clearly this goes to 0 as n grows. However, if your cov matrix is different, then it can be anything. You can choose C such that PC1 explains 100% of the variance with any n. This remains an ill-posed question.

Comment: @ amoeba. Thanks, that's helpful. I guess if the test was a test for the presence of structure vs. noise, it'd make sense to use the identity as the null. Is there a way to test a correlation matrix's eigenvalues against a null of a predefined, non-diagonal correlation matrix? I.e. is there a 'generalized' Marcenko Pastur distribution? With regards to (2): I had data with common structure in mind, i.e. random variables that had ~70% of their variability explained by a common factor. I simulated the results and they line up with intution: the PC R-squared remains stable as you increase n

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look the Wikipedia entry "Random Matrix" . Among other things It provides pointers to the  work of Marcenko-Pastur which may be of interest if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: As far as I understand, this distribution requires the data matrix entries to be i.i.d. i.e. a diagonal correlation matrix